# Filter parent objects which have no children object using prefetch_related

Tags: django

I have three models as following, with `Seller` as the grandparent, `Genre` as the parent and `Book` as the chidlren:

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Genre(models.Model):
    seller= models.ForeignKey(Seller, related_name="genre",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    genre= models.ForeignKey(Genre, related_name="book",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

If I use `prefetch_related()` to fetch the `Seller` objects along with their `Genre` and `Book` as following in one single databse query:

```
sellers = Seller.objects.prefetch_related('genre__book').filter()
```

However, I would like to filter out `Seller` objects that have no `Book` objects related to. What would be the syntax for the `filter()` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

To filter genres that have no books in it you need the following condition:

```
genres = Genre.objects.exclude(pk__in=[x.genre.pk for x in Book.objects.all()]
```

To combine it with `prefetch_related` I think you need to use `Prefetch` object  with a given queryset

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

sellers = Seller.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('genre_set', 
             queryset=Genre.objects.exclude(pk__in=[x.genre.pk for x in Book.objects.all()])
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This ```genres = Genre.objects.exclude(pk__in=[x.genre.pk for x in Book.objects.all()]``` works as expected (although it is the opposite of my filter intention, so I change ```exclude``` to ```filter```. But when using with ```Prefetch``` and ```prefetch_related``` above, the query always returns the entire list of ```Seller``` objects in the database. i.e. it is not filtering out those with empty ```Book```. Mayeb something about ```Prefetch```? I am checking this out further.

Comment: I can suggest also to try: `sellers = Seller.objects.select_related('genre__book').filter(pk__in=[x.genre.pk for x in Book.objects.all()])` Probably this is what you're looking for